# How can I simulate a single car crash without ruining a vehicle?

Tags: recording, budget, field-recording

I'm filming a relatively low budget horror film with a few friends, so we don't have any fancy equipment for this. The shot is supposed to be a guy driving then suddenly swerving the car off the road, maybe into a tree or, even better, ending upside down. Is there a good looking way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can record at 5× the normal frame rate, using a 1/25<sup>th</sup> scale model car will look somewhat realistic.
Things that roll over or bounce, or even fall off a cliff, will appear correct.

Yes, it will still look fake and cheesy, but perhaps that's what you want.